# How can I groupBy and change content of the value in couchbase?

Tags: json, couchbase

Exple :

I have a result like this

Result1 AFTER EMIT:

Key-------------------------------value

"2014/10/31" -----------------   {"A":a}

"2014/10/31" -----------------   {"B":b}

"2014/10/31"-----------------    {"C":c}

"2014/10/31"-----------------  {"D":d}

How can I output this new result from the previous one:

Key-------------------------value

"2014/10/31" -----------------{"Array":["A":a, "B":b, "C":c, "D":d]}

Is there a way? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it . Just do : group = true in the path or select it from the filter result .
and a reduce function to return all the values from the map. also you can add the start key = "2014/10/31" and end key= "2014/10/31".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Couchbase v3 new [N1QL query language](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-query-language-0.1/) for that. Also there is [Query Language Tutorial](http://query.pub.couchbase.com/tutorial). Specifically [Array Comprehensions](http://query.pub.couchbase.com/tutorial/#22) syntax.